# How to redirect to a new page after a successful POST API call in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have the following code in my js file.

```
    $scope.addLookupAction = function () {
        $("#importForm").attr("action", 'xyz.com');

        success:function(response) {
            $log.info("Redirecting to lookup home page");
            window.location.href='abc.com';
        }
    };
```

I am trying to redirect the application to a new page(abc.com) on receiving a good http response(200) from 'xyz.com'. Any pointers on why this does not work? I have a bit of angularjs and jquery together which makes it even more convoluted...

Also, this is my first post on stack overflow... So Hello everyone !!! :)

Comment: You should be using `$http service`..

Comment: where is http post in the code fragment, also its having syntax error. if problem is only with redirect try adding "http://" before domain name

Comment: So instead of `$("#importForm").attr("action", 'xyz.com')`, should I be using $http service ?

Comment: @Dileep I haven't used http post, I had used `.attr` property of jquery to call the API

Comment: his mean use  window.location.href='http ://abc.com';

Comment: adding attr will not post, it just sets target and will be used on next form submit. and about hanging success property in method body, arent u getting syntax err?

Comment: Ah yes.. I hadn't noticed that..I am just going to go the $http way here. Seems easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the function called when you click a button?

First you need to inject the $location and $http.

```
$scope.addLookupAction = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $http.post('xyz.com').then(function () { 
        $location.href = 'abc.com';
    });
};
```

Comment: That's right. When i click on a button having ng-click bound to the above function, a certain POST API gets called

Comment: Probably this solution will work. If it works mask as solution, please. If it didn't work tell me what happens.

Comment: Thanks @Rodrigo. This solution worked perfectly. AngularJS rocks!!

Answer (score 0):

Inject `$location` to your controller:

```
$location.path('http://exmaple.com').replace()
```

Comment: Hmm. but I need to create browser history(apologies for forgetting to mention that) when I redirect.. and replace would not log anything in the browser history

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `href`, but should add `http://`;

```
$scope.addLookupAction = function () {
    $("#importForm").attr("action", 'xyz.com');

    success:function(response) {
        $log.info("Redirecting to lookup home page");
        window.location.='http://example.com';
    }
};
```

Comment: Ah.. but I cannot change the URL that is sent to me ..which is why I have to carry on on with whatever I get from an external service. But i did check the URL which is being sent over and it seems to have the http:// prefix.. Anyways, $http.post solved the issue for me.. Thanks for all the help !

Answer (score 0):

You can try this working for me..

```
e.preventDefault();
$http.post('xyz.com').then(function () { 
    window.location = jQuery('.btn').attr('href');
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Gautam.. I did use something like this. Worked perfectly for me